# ext 4-1 TreePanel Locked column

Tags: extjs, treepanel

i have use property locked in treepanel column, and my console report problem :

```
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
        text: 'Task',
        locked:true,
        flex: 2,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'task',
    }
```

ERROR IS: ext-debug.js:10872
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but you have an extra comma after `dataIndex: 'task'`.

Comment: this is not a problem, i have post in sencha forum, and admin says 'Ext js 4.1 not suported locked column in treePanel'.. thankx